# Updating files on GCE Instances with Autoscale

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I am trying to set up autoscale on GCE.

Below is an overview of the network structure i am trying to built.

Let us say that I have only one file index.php which should be present on every GCE Instance to serve the users.

I have stored the index.php file on GCS.

Now what I have done till now is:

1. Created an instance template with startup script to install apache and then fetch the file from GCS and save in www folder.
2. Created an instance group with autoscaling on and maximum two servers.
3. Set up load balancer on instance group to balance the load.

Now, if due to traffic 2 VM instances are running and I want to make some changes in the index.php file.

How can I update the file (on GCS as well as 2 VM Instances running)? Do I need to create a PHP file which should copy the modified file to all the available Instances as well as GCS? I am totally confused on this.

Comment: Once you update your PHP file you can upload it to GCS bucket and then ssh into your running instances in the group and copy the file to these instances. The new instances created in the group through autoscaler will have the updated file if the name and path of the file is same in startup script. These steps for updating the file can be automated in a shell script.

Comment: Thank you Faizan for the answer. So, should I write the shell script in a php file? or is there any other method to do the same?

Comment: I would recommending writing the script separately and than running it from your local machine or GCE instance once you update your PHP file.